# don't understand warning: no profile detected using WebBrick. assistance needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

WARNING:

```
   No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
```

I tried uploading my app to heroku, and after git push heroku master, I see this warning and when i add heroku open, my page did not load. I do not understand the problem nor the warning after clicking on the link. please clarify and help, if you can. thanks.

Comment: Where's the screenshot ?

Comment: run this command - echo "web: bundle exec rails server thin -p \$PORT -e \$RACK_ENV" > Procfile

Comment: There is no issue with this warning see this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4. If you didn't run `rake db:migrate` then first do that then run `heroku open` command. Other things also mention in url. Hope that help you!

Comment: Also do include 'thin' in your gemfile

Comment: @NitinVerma - I guess it should be heroku run rake db:migrate , which runs the migrations by connecting to the terminal

Comment: Yes it should be `heroku run rake db:migrate` I just provided hint all the things mention in url. Also warning is also mention there.